# Unexpected newline happens after capitalize method

Tags: python, printing, newline, python-3.6

Why is the output forcing a new line on the result when there isn't a `\n` after `print (message_2.capitalize())`?

```
# Input example python script
# Apparently in python 3.6, inputs can take strings instead of only raw values back in v2.7

message_0 = "good morning!"
message_1 = "please enter something for my input() value:"
message_2 = "the number you entered is ... "
message_3 = "ok, now this time enter value for my raw_input() value:"
message_final1 = "program ended." 
message_final2 = "thank you!"

print ("\n\n")
print (message_0.capitalize() + "\n")
input_num = input(message_1.capitalize())
print ("\n")

# This line is obsoleted in python 3.6. raw_input() is renamed to input() . 
# raw_input_num = raw_input(message_3.capitalize())


# data conversion

print ("Converting input_num() variable to float...\n")
input_num = float(input_num)


print ("\n")
print (message_2.capitalize()) 
print (input_num)


print ("\n")
print (message_final1.capitalize() + " " + message_final2.capitalize())
```

Output is as follows:

```
Good morning!

Please enter something for my input() value:67.3


Converting input_num() variable to float...

The number you entered is ...
67.3


Program ended. Thank you!
```

Answer (score 1):

`print()`, by default, will add a newline. So the two statements:

```
print (message_2.capitalize()) 
print (input_num)
```

will put a newline in between the message and the number.

Either pass in both objects to print to **one** `print()` call:

```
print(message_2.capitalize(), input_num)
```

or tell `print()` not to add a newline by setting the `end` argument to an empty string:

```
print(message_2.capitalize(), end='')
print(input_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) function's default behavior is to print a newline follwing the input string.

You can change this behavior by adding the optional parameter `end`:

```
print("My message", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've asked my friends around, and rather than just deleting my question I thought to add value to this site by sharing the answer :

```
# , operator here removes an unexpected newline. the print statement has a built in newline. That's why! 
print (message_2.capitalize(),(input_num),"\n")

# Alternative way to display the answer
print (message_2.capitalize() + " " + str(input_num))
```

So the key is to use a comma operand or do a string operator on the answer.